# command pattern, why does this not work

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am implementing a command pattern in android.

This is what I have right now. For some reason this does not run. It is like the AddUserRequest is getting garbage collected for some reason.

RequestManager.java:

```
public class RequestManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final RequestManager instance = new RequestManager();
private boolean isConnected = false;
private static ArrayList<Request> requestQueue = new ArrayList<Request>();

private RequestManager() {
}

/* singleton class */
public static RequestManager getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void invokeRequest(Request request) {
    request.execute(); // only to test this, this will change
    return;
}
}
```

AddUserRequest.java

```
public class AddUserRequest extends InsertionRequest {
User user;

public AddUserRequest(User user) {
     this.user = user;
}

public void execute() {
    System.out.println("TEST!!!");
}
}
```

Request.java:

```
public abstract class Request {

public abstract void execute();

}
}
```

InsertionRequest.java

```
public abstract class InsertionRequest extends Request {
```

}

RequestManagerTest.java

```
public class RequestManagerTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
public RequestManagerTest(){
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

public void testAddUserRequest() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Tester12345");

    AddUserRequest request = new AddUserRequest(user);
    RequestManager.getInstance().invokeRequest(request);
}
}
```

For some reason this does not print "TEST!!!" and for the life of me I cannot figure out why. I looked in the debug log and everytime request.execute() in RequestManager.java gets called there is a "GC Explicit..." which I suspect has to do with garbage collection. What is the proper way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: what is `InsertionRequest`?

Comment: Sorry for missing that, that extends the regular Request, since AddUserRequest will eventually insert into ES I've decided to make a subclass called InsertionRequest for classes that insert into the db.

Comment: @user3258845 Don’t comment on your question; edit the question to provide the missing information.

Comment: hi AJ, the information has been updated. Please let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Stupid question:  Would it be because the public class `RequestManagerTest` is inside a file named TestRequestManager.java, instead of RequestManagerTest.java?

Comment: Hi AJ, good eye, unfortunately that is just a mistake, I will update that shortly. I am starting to think I am having troubles with the JUNIT test environment.

Comment: @AJNeufeld sof highly encourage to maintain a positive behaviour among users. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/